# Are these related in etymology: oculus, nox or noctis, and noceo?

Tags: etymology

I was wondering if the following three word roots are related from the perspective of etymology:

- oculus: eye, or puncture or hole. e.g. inoculate
- nox, noctis: "night,"  e.g. nocturnal
- noceo: injure. e.g. innocuous, innocent.

Are the first two both related to light?

Are the first and last both related to puncture or hole?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, these are from different roots. I take all this from Wiktionary, but I checked De Vaan, too, to ensure accuracy.

**oculus**

> From Proto-Italic **okʷelos*, from Proto-Indo-European **h₃ókʷ-*, **h₃ekʷ-* (“eye; to see”), probably through a later root **ōkʷelos*.

**nox**

> From Proto-Italic **nokts*, from Proto-Indo-European **nókʷts*.

Pooth then derives **nókʷts* from **negʷ-*, "bare, naked." But De Vann has the more immediate PIE form as *nogʷʰ-t-s, "night."

**noceo**

> From Proto-Italic **nokeō*, from Proto-Indo-European **noḱéye-*, causative of the root **neḱ-* ("perish, disappear" as Wiktionary puts it, related to the Greek *nekros*).

Despite looking similar, **neḱ-* and **negʷ-* are different roots.